# Web Crawler Detecting Vue Broken Links

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue to get store locations based on the location entered. Here is the Vue component:

```
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'key',
    libraries: 'places'
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '.branch-locator',
  data: {
    autocompleteRestrictions: {
      country: 'gb'
    },
    searching: false,
    branches: []
  },
  methods: {
    search(location) {
      this.searching = true;
      Axios.post('/branch-locator', location.geometry.location)
        .then((response) => {
          this.searching = false;
          this.branches = response.data;

          const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
          for (let branch of this.branches) {
            bounds.extend({
              lat: branch.lat,
              lng: branch.lng
            })
          }
          this.$refs.map.$mapObject.fitBounds(bounds)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          this.searching = false;
        });
    }
  },
  components: {
    VueGoogleMaps
  },
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
{% verbatim %}
<h4>{{ branch.title }}</h4>
<p><a :href="branch.store_link" target="_blank">Store locator</a> | <a :href="branch.maps_link" target="_blank">View on Google Maps</a></p>
{% endverbatim %}
```

This works as expected and is completely fine from a practical sense. However web crawlers detect "branch.store_link" etc as broken links because Vue isn't running in time I'd assume. What would be the easiest what to avoid web crawlers picking these up as broken links?

Answer (score 1):

Try [using `v-cloak`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak).

Declare the CSS:

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

And add the directive to your instance:

```html
<div class="branch-locator" v-cloak>
```

This way it will be hidden until Vue processes it, so the crawler should not pick it up.